# d3 js linear scale bar position and height in stacked to multiple charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using [Mike Bostock's example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4679202) as a template and building on it. [My bar chart here](https://bkamapantula.github.io/ed/).

After transition to stacked version, I am unable to get the y position of the bars. Bars of higher height overshadow the smaller ones. Most likely because of the valueOffset attribute of the stack. I am stuck on this issue for few days now.

Changes from Mike's example:

1. removed group labels in stacked chart
2. new y-axis `y2` on linear scale. The domain for this axis is from 0 to the maximum of all the sums of values in each year which is 141.
3. defined new stack `stack_year` for relative positions of the bars.

Relevant code:

```
// y2 definition
y2.domain([0, d3.max(dataByGroup_year, function(d) { return d.year_wise_sum; })]).range([height, 0]);

// calculates sum of all wins per year
dataByGroup_year.forEach(function(d) {
  var order = d.values.map(function(d) { return d.value; });
  d.year_wise_sum = d3.sum(order);
});

function transitionStacked() {
    var t = svg.transition().duration(750),
    g = t.selectAll(".group").attr("transform", "translate(0," + y0(y0.domain()[0]) + ")");
    g.selectAll("rect").attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.year); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return height - y2(d.valueOffset); }) 
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y2(d.value); });
    g.selectAll(".group-label").text("");
}
```

`y0` is the ordinal scale used for multiple charts. `y1` is the linear scale used for each chart in multiple charts.

[Full HTML code at github](https://github.com/bkamapantula/bkamapantula.github.io/blob/master/ed/index.html)

Data used: [input file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bkamapantula/bkamapantula.github.io/master/ed/multiple.csv). I disabled tips for each bar.

Update: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bkamapantula/pdwbd5ge/1/)

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Make a fiddle if you could..

Comment: Your data needs cleaning up a little ("West Bengal" has 2 values for 1971, "Himachal Pradesh" has 2 for 1967, and there are repetitions for "Manipur" and "Punjab" too). They're causing some problems with offset calculations (although there are other issues too). Can you fix the data, and I'll continue to look at the code. Here's what I have so far, although I will explain the fixes properly when it's done: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/wL9x6cjk/1/

Comment: thanks for noticing the issues henry.. I'm cleaning up the data, will notify once done.

Comment: cleaned up the data, should be good now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a number of issues here, which I've fixed up in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/wL9x6cjk/4/

Part of the problems was the data itself (as per my comment above). There were some repeated values, which was causing issues when calculating the `valueOffset` correctly (using the `d3.layout.stack`)

I've also made some changes to how the `y` and attribute for each `rect` are calculated in the `transitionStacked` function. I changed what you had:

```
.attr("y", function(d) { 
    return height - y2(d.valueOffset); 
})
```

to:

```
.attr("y", function (d) {
    return y2(d.value + d.valueOffset) - height;
})
```

Note that you need to sum the `d.value` and `d.valueOffset`, before applying the scaling, to calculate the top left corner position of the rect. Additionally, you don't need to recalculate the `x` attribute value since this doesn't change between the two chart views, so I removed it

I also removed the call to `stack_year(dataByGroup_year);`. You don't need to build the stack layout here, just to calculate the maximum sum per year.

Finally I also tidied up the y-axis positioning a bit so there's enough space for the x-axis labels, and simplified the positioning of `group` elements in the stacked view. I also moved the x-axis to be appended to `svg` rather than `group`, which simplified positioning of elements